# Merge 2 foreach loops (Deleting files with specific extensions)

Tags: c#, foreach

I got the following code :

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(generationDir, "*.xaml")
{
    File.Delete(file);
}

foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(generationDir, "*.cs")
{
    File.Delete(file);
}
```

I'd like to merge these 2 foreach in a single loop ? Is that possible ?
I'm not comfortable with lambda expression so got a hard time here...

Comment: Seems redundant to do `.GetFiles(generationDir, "*.cs")` AND `.Where(item => item.EndsWith(".cs")`

Comment: Note that the where clause would not be redundant if any of the extensions being searched for were exactly 3 characters long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (var file in 
         Directory.GetFiles(generationDir, "*.*")
                  .Where(item => item.EndsWith(".xaml") || item.EndsWith(".cs")))
                   {
                       File.Delete(file);
                   }
```

For those who like `ForEach()` "sequence operator fake" :) 
(*Please be aware of [“foreach” vs “ForEach”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) before usign it*)

```
Directory.GetFiles(generationDir, "*.*")
         .Where(item => item.EndsWith(".xaml") || item.EndsWith(".cs"))
         .ToList()
         .ForEach(item => File.Delete(item))
```

If you are usign .NET Framework v4 you can use more efficient [Directory.EnumerateFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) method:

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows: When you
>   use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of names
>   before the whole collection is returned; when you use GetFiles, you
>   must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can
>   access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and
>   directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.
>
> The returned collection is not cached; each call to the GetEnumerator
>   on the collection will start a new enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

You can just union the two sets

```
var items = Directory.GetFiles(generationDir, "*.xaml").Where(item => item.EndsWith(".xaml"))
               .Union(Directory.GetFiles(generationDir, "*.cs").Where(item => item.EndswWith(".cs"))
```

Then foreach through them.

By the way, the where clause on each of the collections seems to be redundant to me, since GetFiles uses the mask you provided, so all of the files should end in .xaml or .cs.

Answer (score 1):

How about with LINQ:

```
var files = from extension in new[] { "xaml", "cs" }
            from fileName in Directory.GetFiles(generationDir, "*." + extension)
            select fileName;

foreach(var file in files)
   File.Delete(file);
```

Or in method syntax:

```
var files = new[] { "xaml", "cs" }
            .SelectMany(extension => Directory.GetFiles(generationDir, "*." + extension))

foreach(var file in files)
   File.Delete(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the filter argument from the `GetFiles` method call and use and `or` in your where clause:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(generationDir).Where(item => item.EndsWith(".cs") || item.EndsWith(".xaml"));
foreach (var file in files)
{
     File.Delete(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this using this operator `||`

```
 foreach (string file in  Directory.GetFiles(generationDir, "*.*") 
                .Where(item => item.EndsWith(".xaml") || item.EndsWith(".cs")) 
                 { 
                    File.Delete(file); 
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filenames = (new[] { "*.cs", "*.xaml" }).SelectMany(
    ext => Directory.GetFiles(generationDir, ext));

foreach(var filename in filenames)
    File.Delete(filename);
```

I also removed the redundant Where statements since you were double filtering on the same criteria as you passed in to `Directory.GetFiles`.